# How to retrieve data from Wordpress Elementor formular sent via Webhook to shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-hook

**Using:**
`Wordpress`, `Elementor`, `PHP`

**What I am trying to do:**
When users are filling out the formular (created from Elementor) with name, email etc., then a custom post is created (type called: `tilmeldinger`). This is working as intended, see code example below.
However, the `$atts` does not seem to pass any data, or am I not extracting the data correct?:

```
function wpc_elementor_shortcode_test( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'name' => '',
      'email' => '',
    ),
    $atts
  );

  $name = $atts['name'];
  $email = $atts['email'];

  $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $email,
    'post_content' => $email,
    'post_type' => 'tilmeldinger',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
  );

  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
}
add_shortcode( 'my_elementor_test', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode_test' );
```

Illustration of the form formular:

[image: Illustration of the form formular]

The name field:

[image: The name field]

The webhook and shortcode:

[image: The webhook and shortcode]

Comment: The `$atts` passed to your shortcode function has nothing whatsoever to do with any posted form data - that is to access attributes you place on the shortcode itself, `[shortcode foo=bar]`, the foo/bar stuff is what you would find in `$atts`. You should use `$_POST` to access anything that was posted via your form.

Comment: Whether you should do this via a shortcode in the first place, would be a different question. That form component your are using there will most likely be providing hooks to intercept the submitted data, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks.. Maybe it would be a better solution just to create form elements directly in the shortcode and not use the elementor form